# uninstalling jupyter PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/jupyter'

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, uninstallation, ubuntu-20.04

i am new with programming and Linux.

i have been installing jupyter notebook unsuccessfully, it didn't open on the browser then i decided to uninstall everything and start it again. unfortunately uninstalling gave me this error

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 791, in move
os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError:

**[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/jupyter' -> '/tmp/pip-** 
uninstall-7g1rn47h/jupyter'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 
160, in exc_logging_wrapper
status = run_func(*args)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 
98, in run
uninstall_pathset = req.uninstall(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 
660, 
in uninstall
uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 
373, in remove
moved.stash(path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 
271, in stash
renames(path, new_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 311, in 
renames
shutil.move(old, new)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 812, in move
os.unlink(src)

**PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/jupyter'**
```

basically have 2 error of permission denided.

i know the problem is with the permission so i tried to change it with chmod  but it didn't work neither.

please some help

I'm working with ubuntu 20.04.5 lts

i have tried already the below commands

```
pip-autoremove jupyter -y

pip-autoremove jupyter-core -y

pip3 uninstall jupyterlab
```

i always have the same error

cheers!

Comment: Did you tried using `sudo` permissions?

Comment: hi Andreja,  i dont know how to do that, as i said before i and learning.  could you please tell me how to check it? cheers!.

Comment: @AndrejaMilosavljevic its done!, i used this command               >>sudo -H python3 -m pip uninstall jupyter_core jupyter_qtconsole nbformat nbconvert notebook<<    problem solve. thanks for the help

Comment: np man, just vote my answer, Edit: flag answer.